# autofocus doesn't work in textbox of dynamic content from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a function in `JS` which gets `HTML` content through `AJAX` and put that in Bootstrap dialog.

Now I've added **autofocus** attribute to the input box which comes within dynamic HTML. The problem is I see the focus on input box for sometime and then it gets disappeared.

**JS code:**

```
function getPage(userid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: PAGE_URL,
        data: {'userid':userid},
        success: function (data) {
            changeDialogContent(data);
        },
        error: function (e, textStatus) {
            alert('Error occured while processing your request');
        }
    });
}
```

`changeDialogContent` function just add the dynamic content to the Dialog as HTML.

```
var bootstrapmodal=$('#modelDiv');
function changeDialogContent(content) {
    bootstrapmodal.html(content);
}
```

**HTML Code of Input:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm someInputBox" autofocus="autofocus" value="0" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
```

I've also tried adding `$('.someInputBox').focus();` just after setting HTML content into Bootstrap dialog, no luck with that too.

Is there anything important I'm missing?

Comment: can you show the code of changeDialogContent?? adding a fiddle might be useful

Comment: _The problem is I see the focus on input box for sometime and then it gets disappeared._....check if page reloads.

Comment: @SamGhatak updated the code, It's just normal function to set content as HTML.

Comment: @Jai No page is not reloading, as it's AJAX it just show HTML content in bootstrap dialog.

Comment: have you tried the `$('.someInputBox').focus();` inside the `changeDialog()` function?

Comment: @andrew yes tried, no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my php code that i assume would be similar to your objective..

test.php:

```
<?php
        echo '<input id="my-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm someInputBox" autofocus="autofocus" value="0" placeholder="Enter Name"/>';

?>
```

HTML and JAVASCRIPT CODE :

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src = "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

        <script>


            function getPage() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: {},
                    success: function (data) {
                        changeDialogContent(data);
                            document.getElementById("my-input").focus();
                    },
                    error: function (e, textStatus) {
                        alert('Error occured while processing your request');
                    }
                });
            }
            function changeDialogContent(content) {
                $('#modelDiv').html(content);
            }   

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getPage()">
        <div id = "modelDiv" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used bower so the source paths of jquery and bootstrap are not cdn. 
And this code works really well.. I didn't encounter any error.
And i am sorry that i can't provide a fiddle as it has a server request and response.. So I tested it on my own machine.

And correct me if i misinterpreted anything.

Comment: I don't want to capture the focus event of input box, I just want my cursor in the textbox when I open the dialog.

Comment: alright alok.. let me implement.. I shall catch you back in a while.

Comment: @Alok Have a look.. I got no error here.. I can even attach the screenshots if you want.

Comment: Does the textbox have Focus when the page is loaded in DOM?

Comment: Yes. It does. Want me to share the screenshot?

Comment: And is the php code fine? I mean thats what the expected response from php right?

Comment: I don't think screenshot would help, I've the same code written and the focus get disappeared after sometime automatically.

Comment: What Browser are you testing it in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114021/discussion-between-alok-and-tirthraj-barot).